# Select class based on condition

Tags: java

I want to implement this concept, where based on my input condition I will get output.

Not so strong on java ..saw many post but yet to solve this  ..

There issue I am getting is "myValue1 or myValue20 cannot be resolved or is not a field".

```
public class myClass extends XXX{
    Object p;

    public myClass() {
        String condition = "";     // Input

        if(condition.equals("Abc"))
            p = new Abc();
        else if(condition.equals("Def"))
            p = new Def();
        else if(condition.equals("Xyz"))
            p = new Xyz();
    }

    public void useMe(){
        System.out.println(p.myValue1);   // output-1
                System.out.println(p.myValue20);   // output-2
    }
}

public class Abc{
    public String myValue1 = "11";
        ..
        public String myValue99 = "9999";
}

public class Def{
    public String myValue = "222";
        ..
        public String myValue99 = "9999";
}

public class Xyz{
    public String myValue = "333";
        ..
        public String myValue99 = "9999";
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to have `Abc`, `Def` etc implement a common interface.  Then have `p` be this interface rather than an `Object`  The error message is correct.  `Object` does not have a field called `myValue`

Comment: @ScaryWombat , thanks for your response. It will be great help if u please give an example code .

Comment: and you can give me you salary (when you get one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a common `interface` that all the three classes implement.

```java
interface ValueProvider {
    String getValue(int index);
}
class Abc implements ValueProvider {
    @Override
    public String getValue(int index) {
        return switch(index) {
            case 1 -> "11";
            case 20 -> "20";
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        };
    }
}
class Def implements ValueProvider {
    @Override
    public String getValue(int index) {
        return switch(index) {
            case 1 -> "222";
            case 20 -> "9999";
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        };
    }
}
class Xyz implements ValueProvider {
    @Override
    public String getValue(int index) {
        return switch(index) {
            case 1 -> "3333";
            case 20 -> "9999";
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        };
    }
}
```

Then, you can declare the type of `p` as that interface rather than `Object`.

```java
public class MyClass {
    ValueProvider p;

    // ...

    public void useMe(){
        System.out.println(p.getValue(1));
        System.out.println(p.getValue(20));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But where should I pass the class name to ensure it fetch that specific value

Comment: @Junior The rest of the code in `MyClass` is still the same as in your question. I just omitted it for brevity in the spot with `// ...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Unmitigated ... u are my job saver .. love u